# Regex for numbers including decimal points

Tags: regex

I'm still trying to pick up regex so I can't seem to figure this one out. I want to be able to match any type of number including things like

```
0.2
.1243
1.
-0.34
+033.98274E-10
-.1e+004
```

I have created the following regex which matches all of these: `[+-]?[0-9+\.]+([E][+-]?[0-9]+)?`, however this also matches single decimal points such as if I had something like `param.attribute`, it would pick up on that decimal point. How can I get around this? I thought that in the part `[0-9+\.]` the `+` would require that the string contain at least one numeric value.

Comment: If it works the way you said, it would not match the `.1234` like you said: it matches at least one numeric value before the dot. It also doesn't match the `e` in your example.

Comment: No, it matches `.1234`. My issue is that the expression above also matches only a single `.` meaning any and all `.` are matched, including those not in numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use alternation to make sure either `1.` or `.1` is matched. Avoid making all subpatterns optional if you do not want to end up with a single period matched:

```
[-+]?(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
     ^--- Alernative 1 | Alternative 2-^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE0iX9/1)

More ["fun" facts about alternation in regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

> You can use alternation to match a single regular expression out of several possible regular expressions.
>   
>   If you want to search for the literal text `cat` or `dog`, separate both options with a vertical bar or pipe symbol: `cat|dog`. If you want more options, simply expand the list: `cat|dog|mouse|fish`.
>   
>   The alternation operator has the lowest precedence of all regex operators. That is, it tells the regex engine to match either everything to the left of the vertical bar, or everything to the right of the vertical bar. If you want to limit the reach of the alternation, you need to use parentheses for grouping.

And here is my 5 cents: to keep the regex match as clean as possible and *unless* you need to access any of the alternatives after a match is found, use non-capturing groups (i.e. `(?: ... )`) with alternations.

Comment: Great thanks! I didn't know about alternation before!

Comment: I have added more about alternation in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposition:

```
[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|0?\.[0-9]+)([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pS4qP8/1)